# How to randomly select n observations in a dataframe?

Tags: r

given a fairly large data frame I want to randomly select 500 observations

```
samp <- sample_n(df,500)
samp
```

doesn't work for some reason it just gives me an error "Error: `size` must be less or equal than 1 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement"

Comment: `df` does not have 500 rows.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0c17d385d9729433c3413c48a91a879b - this is the dataframe im using it says 976 rows

Comment: What is `class(df)` ?

Comment: [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the dataframe is grouped it is trying to take 500 observations from each group. `ungroup` the dataframe and then use `sample_n`.

```
library(dplyr)
samp <- df %>% ungroup() %>% sample_n(500)
```

In base R, we can use `sample` directly without ungrouping.

```
samp <- df[sample(nrow(df), 500), ]
```